# Не получайется подключить css файл

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

Я недавно открыл свой проект и слетел `css`. До этого такого не было.
Вот ошибка:

> Ресурс с «http://localhost:3000/home.css» был заблокирован из-за
>   несоответствия MIME-типа («text/html») (X-Content-Type-Options:
>   nosniff)

Шапка

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css">
<title>My site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Вот css :

```
.navbar{
    background: #F2801C;
}
.navbar-link, .navbar-brand{
    color: white;
}
.navbar-link{
    margin-right: 1em;
    color: white;
}
```

Вот код сервера на node js:

```
const expr  = require('express'),
app         = expr(),
PORT        = process.env.PORT || 3000,
mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient,
path        = require('path'),
path_       = path.dirname(__dirname) + '/client'
assert      = require('assert');

app.get('/', (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(`${path_}/home.html`)
})
app.get('/about', (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(`${path_}/about.html`)
})
app.listen(PORT);
```

Comment: Так Ваш сервер умеет отдавать ровно два файла - `home.html` и `about.html` из подкаталога `client`. Ни о каком `home.css` он понятия не имеет.

Answer (score 1):

В вашем сервера есть только 2 пути:

> /
>   /about

Просто попробуйте добавить 3-тий путь:

```js
app.get('/home.css', (req, res) =>{
    res.sendFile(`${path_}/home.css`)
})
```

Это очень просто, но должно работать.

Но я бы посоветовал создать папку (например «public») и поместить туда всё статические файлы (стили, изображения).

```js
app.use("/public", express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
```

**Использование:**

```
http://localhost:3000/public/путь/к/файлу.css
```

Или

```
http://localhost:3000/public/файл.css
```

Comment: спасибо сработало

Comment: @LeMoN Попробуйте обновленный код. Думаю что он будет полезнешым

Answer (score 0):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css" type="text/css">
```